# NFS stopped working after upgrade

Tags: upgrade, kernel, mount, fstab, nfs

After upgrade, NFS modules stopped loading into kernel, `/proc/fs/nfsd` stopped being mounted.

Using modprobe to load the NFS modules successfully installs, but when attempting to `mount -t nfsd /proc/fs/nfsd`, it complains about not being in the `/etc/fstab`.  Since `nfsd` isn't mounted, all the other NFS services fail.

This is what `systemd` reports:

```
May 10 04:46:49 Cuckoo-Database systemd[1]: nfs-idmapd.service: Job nfs-idmapd.service/start failed with result 'dependency'.
May 10 04:46:49 Cuckoo-Database systemd[1]: Dependency failed for NFS Mount Daemon.
-- Subject: A start job for unit nfs-mountd.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- A start job for unit nfs-mountd.service has finished with a failure.
-- 
-- The job identifier is 984 and the job result is dependency.
May 10 04:46:49 Cuckoo-Database systemd[1]: nfs-mountd.service: Job nfs-mountd.service/start failed with result 'dependency'.
May 10 04:46:49 Cuckoo-Database systemd[1]: nfs-server.service: Job nfs-server.service/start failed with result 'dependency'.
May 10 04:46:49 Cuckoo-Database systemd[1]: nfs-idmapd.service: Unit is bound to inactive unit nfs-server.service. Stopping, too.
May 10 04:46:49 Cuckoo-Database systemd[1]: Stopping NFSv4 ID-name mapping service...
```

I attempted to reinstall `nfs-common` and `nfs-kernel-server`, but this didn't solve the issue.